# What happens if I drop partitions in a table?

Tags: partitioning, database-partitioning

I have few questions regarding the partitions, I'm planning to drop the existing partition scheme/function in table1 and then point the new partition scheme/function to table1 (I know how to go ahead with the process but before that I would like to know some suggestions/answers to the below queries )

1. If I drop the old/existing partition scheme/function with data in the table what Will happen to the data in old partition.ndf files ? (deleted / Not modified)
2. If I drop the old/existing partition scheme/function with data in the table what Will happen to the data in the table ? (will there be any loss of records)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer for the question I raised.

1. Even though the partitions are droped from an existing table the filegroup/files will have its data. After partition drop if any data is added to the table then those data won't be there in the filegroup/files.
2. There won't be any data loss for this condition.